# How to get spontaneous output from 1 million records which are updating in microseconds?

Tags: php, mysql, response

One of our gaming application which is build with PHP, MySQL, React and Redis having million concurrent users. I would like to get fastest out put of leaderboard position of prompt leader and lagger.

Please suggest me the best way to find the contestant in quick time with less load.

Comment: No clue. How's the leaderboard data stored? What's your database schema? Indexing? Caching? C'mon, we'd need a lot more detail than this.

Comment: Database is MySQL. Indexing is already established. Redis is caching server. What else do you need?